# Making Anchors work when you duplicate a section and hiding one for mobile and one for desktop

Tags: wordpress, menu, duplicates, anchor, responsive

So here is what I'm trying to do.  I have a fancy set up for desktop that doesn't work for mobile. So what I've done is create another section for mobile. The sections have anchors to jump to the correct positions. But since I have one section (with the anchors) hidden on desktop and the other (same anchors) hidden on mobile the links to the anchors don't work (same header menu referencing the link/#anchor)   I'm guessing because I have duplicate anchors and "hidden" doesn't stop it from reading the anchors?

I have one menu.. I'm not great at code.. so not sure how to tell the same header/menu to jump to the "mobile" section anchor when on mobile.
Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, CSS ID names need to be unique on a page.
You could set the anchor on an element just before both sections, even if it's just an empty space.